# Begin/End/While in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best approach to do this?

```
@user = UserFinder.find(first_name: "Dave")
if !@user
  return render :text => '// No user named Dave found'
end

if @user.last_name != "Edwards"
  # This is not the guy we want
  @user.destroy

  # Now we want to re-execute the search again forever until we find Dave Edwards
end
```

Keep in mind this is an incredibly simplistic example of the real code I have, so I know that I can just filter the query in the first place, but I want it this way.

I'm not sure how to do this with `begin` and `while` blocks because destroying an unwanted user is required if we run into one.

My Attempts:

---

```
begin
  @user = UserFinder.find(first_name: "Dave")
  return render :text => '// No user named Dave found'
end while @user.destroy if @user.last_name != "Edwards"
```

This doesn't work because the `while` block gets the result of `destroy` not the comparison of `last_name`

*P.S. Just if this is impossible this way, How to reload the Rails controller action with the same params?*

Comment: @Nate it returns a User object, or nil if nothing is found.

Comment: I am assuming that you will return that text whenever @user is nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
begin
  @user = UserFinder.find_by_first_name("Dave")
  render :text => '// No user named Dave found' if @user.nil?
  return if @user.nil?
end while @user.last_name != "Edwards" && @user.destroy
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if `return` would just break the begin block instead of the whole rails action. the latter is what i want. what do you think?

Comment: Thanks Anand, Nice compact approach

Comment: return after render, the controller action will not stop after render

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
while (@user = UserFinder.find(first_name: "Dave")) and @user.last_name != "Edwards"
  @user.destroy
end

if @user
  render ...
else
  render :text => '// No user named Dave found'
end
```

Comment: If UserFinder returns nil, then @user is nil, `while` loop will exit. The code won't break.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.destroy while user = UserFinder.where(:first_name => "Dave",  :last_name => "Edwards").first
```